# Sql выборка с математическим запросом из строковых полей

Tags: sql, pdo

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE val >= ? AND val <= ?
```

Такой запрос выдаст правильный результат, если поле val INT или DECIMAL, но в базе это поле текстового типа и некоторые данные содержут кроме строк целые или десятичные числа.

Есть ли какой-то метод получить правильное значение? Спасибо.

Comment: `WHERE val + 0 BETWEEN ? AND ?` Это если надо преобразовать строку в число. Но если попадётся не-число, то скорее всего будет выдано сообщение об ошибке (зависит от текущего SQL Mode).

Comment: @Akina Я пробовал это, это не работает даже если находить числа между. А мой вариант в ответе работает четко.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CAST(val AS FLOAT) >= ? AND CAST(val AS FLOAT) <= ?
```